# Can't get div to float all the way to the right

Tags: css, html

How come when I float #main div to the right, the right border doesn't line up with the right border of the header div?

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

html, body {
     height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
     width: 960px;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
     width: 960px;
     height: 70px;
     border: 1px solid black;         
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     margin-top: 20px;
}

#leftcol {
     width: 250px;
     height: 500px;
     border: 1px solid black; 
     float: left;
     margin-right: 20px;          
 }

 #main {  
    width: 686px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:right;
 }
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="leftcol">
      </div>  
      <div id="main">
      </div>
    </div><!--end wrapper-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your mark-up as well? It's hard to give you a solution without being able to see your HTML.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnaD8/

Comment: To me it is really hard to tell whether they line up or not, and I have to zoom in to see any difference. Are you really that worried about this little issue?

Comment: With a 1px border, it is very hard to tell, but once you have a border like 4px it becomes very noticeable. I am new to CSS and am only worried about it to the extent that I want to understand what is happening so it doesn't cause me bigger problems down the road. I just don't want to get in the habit of overlooking issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to consider the border width of the header.
In total, your header's width is `960px` + `2px` from the border = `962px`, while the main content plus the sidebar have a width of `960px`.

If you set the header's width to `958px`, both divs align.

Here's a reference to the CSS box model to help you do the math: [CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: AH! I knew it was something simple! Thanks soo much!

Answer (score 2):

As @alfonso pointed out, borders are increasing the actual size of your divs.

It's good practice to use `box-sizing: border-box` on all the elements with borders, so that the borders go inside. Alignment becomes MUCH easier.

Comment: Thank you, I'd never heard of that. Will look into it